# Импорт материалов для мобилок

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

Я импортирую в unity некий объект в формате .fbx он импортирует с собой еще материалы, но у него все материалы имеют шейдер стандарт, как мне сделать эти материалы с шейдером под мобилки?

Comment: как ни странно: поменяй шейдер и примени нужные текстуры на этот шейдер.

Comment: @Andrew забыл уж об этой теме, но там же не доступно редактирования ни материала ни самого объекта.

Comment: ты можешь создать свой материал и повесить на меш.

Comment: @Andrew да, но как я могу это сделать, если на меше несколько материалов? Они все забьються в один.

Comment: если меш состоит с нескольки мешей, ты можешь применять материалы отдельно к каждой части. Если это один... то я не уверен возможно ли на 1 меш нацепить несколько материалов в принципе :)

Comment: @Andrew дело в том что меш один, сделан он в 3д редакторе и там все цвета наложены, в юнити же цвета располагаються так же но с шейдерами для пк, если закинуть один материал на объект то он заменит все сразу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я посмотрел, в юнити на один меш ты не можешь нацепить несколько материалов. Использовать внешние материалы я не советую в принципе  их саппорт весьма ограничен и они, банально, не заточены под юнити.

Окроме того даже если бы юнити саппортил бы несколько материалов на один меш, то это было бы плохой практикой. Т.к. каждый материал делает `drawcall` – вызов отрисовки. А это достаточно сложная и грузная операция.

Решением является один из следующих вариантов:

- Разделить (split) меш в 3д редакторе в нужных местах
- Составить хорошую развертку и применить один единственный материал на весь обьект. Вместе с теми мапами которые тебе нужны. Отдельно диффуз, отдельно бамп (если имеется), отдельно спекулар (если имеется)

**Второй вариант – лучше.**

Comment: @Andew первый вариант мне понравился, легк в реализации, но вот я не понимаю как сделать развертку (не важно какой 3д редактор) из нескольких материлов

Comment: `в юнити на один меш ты не можешь нацепить несколько материалов` с каких это пор? Unity как раз позволяет рендерить один и тот же меш 1 и *более* материалами. Да, это медленно, но зато позволяет сделать 1 и более проходов с помощью разных шейдеров вместо 1 шейдера с 2 и более проходами :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker тогда, лучше, добавить ответ в котором будет говорится как это делать. Для будущих поколений, так сказать